# JSP form submission error

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

Hey i am working on a Spring MVC project, i need to perform client side validation before i submit the form to the server, but the problem i am facing is that when i click on submit the form is getting submitted and the the `function doClick()` is not being executed at all. 
Also tell me if this is the right way to access the data "`userName`" & "`password`" in the javascript function.

this is the javascript function. 
    enter code here

```
function doClick()
    {
      alert("yo");
    var a= document.getElementById("un").value;

    var b=document.getElementById("pwd").value;
     var n="/0";
    if(a.equals(n) && b.equals(n))
        {alert ("Enter the login credentials");
        return (false);
        }

        else 
        return true;
     }
```

This is the form tag.

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="loginForm" action="login" onsubmit=" doClick()"      >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>UN :</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" id="un"/></td>
            <td><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="password" id="pwd" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" /></td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this for the form attribute, it will invoke the function; true - will submit, false - won't submit form:

```
onsubmit="return doClick();"
```